# How to sort pictures by name with some program?

Tags: windows, sorting, filenames, photos

You all know it - you have pictures from vacation and other life events and you decide that you will sort photos you want them to be as you wish together. My question is related to this.

How can I easily sort photos by moving them? I mean - when you have pictures named, e.g., `IMG_001.jpg`, `IMG_002.jpg`, `IMG_086.jpg`, `PIC_870.jpg`, `887766.jpg`, etc., and you want one naming and sorting by only moving them?

I heard from my friend there is some program where you have pictures you choose and by moving them it will sort them and name them accordingly. Is there anything like this for Windows 7? This is really hard to find on internet, so I am asking here, I hope somebody knows more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-rename-utility.htm) is a site reviewing a handful of bulk file rename utilities. Some let you define a renaming method, where for example files named IMG_001.jpg, IMG_002.jpg, etc. are renamed *en masse* with maybe more descriptive names. Hopefully one of these will help, though only the one named Bulk Rename Utility appears to come anywhere close to having a visual interface where you can drag-and-drop files to rename.

Comment: This sounds good the first one listed seems not to have any view on the photos but now I know how to look I hope.

Comment: @DarthContinent - It's probably better not to answer off-topic questions as it encourages the posting of such questions.

Comment: Off-topic? Is there any topic?

Comment: Oh my bad i did not know there are so many forums like this :)

Comment: @JamesAllardice ahh understood.